# PowerShell equavalent code for C#

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and have struggled to convert below C# code into Powershell.

```
var vmDoc = XDocument.Load(vmStream);
var vmElement = vmDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
        .Descendants(ns + "content");
var vmId = vmElement.Descendants().Descendants(nsData + "VirtualMachineID").FirstOrDefault();
```

I tried below code but it never worked

```
$vmElement = vmDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
    $_.Descendants($ns + "content")
$vmId = $vmElement.Descendants().Descendants($nsData + "VirtualMachineID").FirstOrDefault()
```

Hope someone could help me!!

Thanks in advance!

Ramani

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've just misunderstood a line break in C#. Line breaks mean nothing and often long lines are continued onto another line for readability. You've mistakenly used the powershell "this pipeline" variable `$_` on line 3.

```
$vmElement = vmDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry").Descendants($ns + "content")
$vmId = $vmElement.Descendants().Descendants($nsData + "VirtualMachineID").FirstOrDefault()
```

<strike>**Edit**: Having reviewed the [documentation for the `Descendants` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx), its not clear that your original C# code would work either. That method returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which would not expose a `Descendants()` method.</strike>

I suggest you concentrate on getting working C# code before trying to convert to Powershell.

This might help you: [Is there an easier way of using extension methods in Powershell v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431727/is-there-an-easier-way-of-using-extension-methods-in-powershell-v2)
And this: http://dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2007/08/07/using-xmllinq-in-powershell/

Comment: thanks for quick response Jamiec! but I got into different error ..PS C:\Work\Scripts> $vmElement = $vmDoc.Descendants($ns + "entry").Descendants($ns + "content")
Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__a] doesn't contain a method named 'Descendants'.
At line:1 char:59
+ $vmElement = $vmDoc.Descendants($ns + "entry").Descendants <<<< ($ns + "content")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Descendants:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: If you can provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) of the problem in C#, i'd be happy to help you debug the powershell.

Comment: Thanks James for getting back to me quickly again.The problem I am having while executing your code caused by extension methods not available in PowerShell. I am wondering how to import (.NET)extensions to Powershell.I wanted to provide my code here but there is space restriction which not allowing me to do so.